# Adverb and adjective modifier

Tags: modifiers

In this sentence, does really good modify player or does just good modify player? "He is a really good player."

Comment: Like most adverbs, it modifies the adjective: a (really good) player.

Answer (score 2):

"Really" is an adverb. In this case it is modifying "good," and "good" is modifying "player."